# I need to detect touch in a masked sprite not(rectangle masked but alpha mask)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, mask, sktexture

when I want to detect touch in a masked (alpha mask) part of a sprite it just prints "a" if I touch a bounding rectangle around the sprite but not only the masked part. in the game that I want write the user moves it's finger without touching any sprite(obstacle) but when I write the code it just prints "a"(means loose) when the user touches a rectangle masked part of the sprite which I don't want what I basically want is to detect touch only I the masked area of the sprite but not the full rectangle surrounding the sprite.
I need to detect touch in a sprite masked like this:

[image]

but not this:

[image]

Comment: See [ask]. Show some code.

Comment: You are aware most people are using their finger to touch the screen, not a pointer or stylus.  Pixel perfect detection is not a good idea for finger pressing, and you may provide your users with a terrible experience.